# shutdownNow method in ExecutorService

Tags: java, concurrency, executorservice

In the following code, I wrote producer-consumer with executor but I do not understand why when I call **shutDownNow()** the **System.out.println(item)** statement is executed twice. in fact, tryLock () returns the wrong value first, and then for the second time the item is printed and then it acquires the lock, and then the interrupt occurs.

```
 public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Deque<String> queue = new ArrayDeque<>();
        ReentrantLock bufferLock = new ReentrantLock();
        Condition fullBuffer = bufferLock.newCondition();

        MyProducer p = new MyProducer(queue, ThreadColor.ANSI_YELLOW, bufferLock, fullBuffer);
        MyConsumer c1 = new MyConsumer(queue, ThreadColor.ANSI_BLUE, bufferLock, fullBuffer);
        MyConsumer c2 = new MyConsumer(queue, ThreadColor.ANSI_BLUE, bufferLock, fullBuffer);

        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
        executorService.execute(p);
        executorService.shutdownNow();
        try {
            executorService.execute(c1);
            executorService.execute(c2);
        } catch (RejectedExecutionException e) {
            System.out.println("no new task has not accepted");
        }
     }
}
```

part of producer code:

```
public class MyProducer implements Runnable {
private final Deque<String> buffer;
private final String color;
private final ReentrantLock bufferLock;
private final Condition fullBuffer;

public MyProducer(Deque<String> buffer, String color, ReentrantLock bufferLock, Condition fullBuffer) {
    this.buffer = buffer;
    this.color = color;
    this.bufferLock = bufferLock;
    this.fullBuffer = fullBuffer;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    String[] items = {"apple", "ball", "laptop", "mouse", "cup", "pc", "pencil", "pen"};
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (String item : items) {
        System.out.println(item);
        try {
            if (bufferLock.tryLock(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
                try {
                    while (items.length == buffer.size()) {
                        try {
                            fullBuffer.await();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            System.out.println(color + "Producer was interrupted");
                        }
                    }

                    System.out.println(color + "Adding:" + item);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(250);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        System.out.println(color + "failed to add");
                    }
                    buffer.add(item);
                    fullBuffer.signalAll();
                } finally {
                    bufferLock.unlock();
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    bufferLock.lock();
    try {
        buffer.add("EOF");
    } finally {
        bufferLock.unlock();
    }
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ":" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + " ms");
}
```

}
[output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcWNx.png)

Comment: You should not omit relevant parts of your code. Since `println` can’t throw an `InterruptedException`, the exception has been caused by the very code within the inner `try { }` block you have omitted, at least when the posted `catch` clause caught it. There seems to be another `catch` clause, as you also have a second `try`, but you forgot to post it…

Comment: Yes, there is an internal catch, but where the exception is thrown is the same catch block that I wrote here.

Comment: It’s impossible for the code you’ve posted that an exception thrown before the `try` is caught by the posted exception handler. That was the point of my comment. Either, the exception has been thrown by a statement you didn’t include or the exception has been caught by a `catch` clause you didn’t include. Or your overall code structure is totally different to what you’ve posted. In either case, what you’ve posted is not helpful for analyzing your problem.

Comment: I put the full code,(MyProducer class).

Comment: I think, you’ve been misguided by the console output due to buffered I/O of two channels (`System.out` and `System.err`). `tryLock` never returned `false`. The remaining output doesn’t fit to your assumption. Replace `e.printStackTrace();` with `e.printStackTrace(System.out);` so it will be serialized with the other output.

Comment: this is the result:  https://pasteboard.co/IaQev1S1kDzb.png.     I think shutDownNow is causing the problem

Comment: What problem? The behavior is exactly like expected. You’re calling `shutDownNow` which interrupts the job, the job’s first call to `tryLock` responds to the interrupt by throwing `InterruptedException`, skipping the entire `if` statement, you catch the `InterruptedException` and proceed with the second item.

Comment: I got it, thank you